# Execute event when I move the map

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to replicate this behavior (https://www.airbnb.ca/s/toronto-ontario?checkin=17-12-2014&checkout=24-12-2014&sw_lat=43.56960969393856&sw_lng=-79.59977045062669&ne_lat=43.8614845983898&ne_lng=-79.23172845843919&zoom=11&search_by_map=true&ss_id=8dvu26gm),

Basically I've been trying to catch the lat/long when when the mouse moves over the map with no success. here is my attempt: http://www.ananietodiseno.com/maps/

I've been trying it using the mouseover event. Is there someone who can point me in the right direction with this subject?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your question with what code you've tried, don't just link to an external site; it'll make your question redundant if you get it working

Comment: Also can you explain what 'this behaviour' is; I'm not seeing anything special when I mouseover the AirBnb map

Comment: One of the things you will need, is something like this: google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", showAlert);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this jQuery:

```
$('.map').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).on("mousemove", updateCoords);
});
$(window).mouseup(function() {
  $(".map").off("mousemove", updateCoords);
});

function updateCoords() {
  // code to run when map is moved
}
```